# Параллельное выполнение функция Python

Tags: python

Всем привет. Есть 2 функции. Функция `look()` будет периодически отправлять запрос на сервер и ждать нужный ответ. Функция `doing()` будет запускаться, если нужный ответ будет получен.

Цель - чтобы функция `doing()` работала параллельно (ее работа может затянуться на день) и могли параллельно работать сразу много функций `doing()`, не мешая работе функции `look()`

```
import time


def doing():
    print('Делаем что-то')
    time.sleep(60)


def look():
    while True:
          print('Ищем что-то')
          if # что-то найдено:
               doing()
```

Comment: Смотрите в сторону threading и subprocess в python

Comment: [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html), [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
import threading
import time

def doing():
    print('Делаем что-то')
    time.sleep(60)


def look():
    while True:
          print('Ищем что-то')
          if # что-то найдено:
               thread = threading.Thread(target = doing)
               thread.start()
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
import threading


def doing():
    print('Делаем что-то')
    time.sleep(60)



def look():
    while True:
          print('Ищем что-то')
          if # что-то найдено:
              start_th = threading.Thread(target = doing)
              start_th.start()
```